# What is the next number for this sequence and the rule(s) that describes it?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, number-sequence

What are the next four numbers and the rule that generates the sequence?

> 0, 2, 8, 24, 64, 160, 384, 896, 2048,  ...

Explain the hints and how you reached the answer once you have got it.

Hint 1:

> The sequence continues indefinitely.

Hint 2:

> These are all whole numbers. No fractions or negatives are in the sequence.

Hint 3:

> Number representations are significant.

Hint 4:

> Consider unusual math operations.

Hint 5:

> Perhaps my own SE activity might be helpful...?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A036289

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next four numbers are

> 4608, 10240, 22528, 49152

As the rule that generates the sequence is

> $f(n) = n \times 2^n$

I got this simply because

> There's a suspiciously high amount of powers of 2 in the sequence

But I have no idea what the hints mean.

---

OP's edit for further explanation and clarification:

> My background is in programming, so the unusual operation is [bitshifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts), and my generating rule was to left-shift the binary representation of *n* by *n* bits.

Comment: This works... but I agree. Perhaps he was looking for something different, since these aren't unusual operations.

Comment: @QuestionAsker If this *isn't* the answer, then you could argue that n<0 doesn't work for hint 2, and the 'real' sequence would.

Comment: It's not quite the way I got the sequence, but I guess that is the formula.